# Excluding the number that appears before sections and using roman numbers in table of content

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, roman-numerals

Whenever I have `\section{something}` a number appears before it, like

> 1.Something

How can I exclude this number?

And for table of content, I have something like

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}
\tableofcontents
```

This works perfectly fine, but I would like to add roman number in some-places in table of content and would like to include, some titles, before `\tableofcontents` command is called into table of content. For example:

```
\section{example}

\setcounter{tocdepth}
\tableofcontents
```

How to include example in the table of content, with roman number in the page column?

My MWE is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside, paper=a4,pagesize=pdftex, liststotoc, bibtotoc]{scrartcl}
%Einstellungen der Seitenrnder
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Umlaute ermglichen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[tight,TABTOPCAP]{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% macros - newly defined by htrsek
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{TODO: #1}}}
\newcommand{\comment}[2]{\textcolor{orange}{\textbf{\textit{\textless Comment (#1): #2\textgreater}}}}
\newcommand{\inprogress}[3]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{InProgress: #1}}}
\newcommand{\translate}[4]{\textcolor{green}{\textbf{(#1)}}}
\newcommand{\flexWARE}{\textsuperscript{flex}WARE }
\newcommand{\thedate}{\today}
%[BC] Using the listing package for source code embedding.
\usepackage{listings} \lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt} \lstset{language=Perl} 

 %PDF Kram
\usepackage[%
    pdftitle={something},% Titel des PDF Dokuments.
    pdfauthor={someone},%Autor des PDF Dokuments.
    pdfsubject={something},%Thema des PDF Dokuments.
    pdfcreator={MiKTeX, LaTeX, hyperref, KOMA-Script},%Erzeuger des PDF Dokuments.
    pdfkeywords={project title},% auch fr PDF 
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,% Inhaltsverzeichnis anzeigen beim 
    %pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,%Dokumenttitel statt Dateiname 
    pdflang=en%Sprache des Dokuments.
]{hyperref}

\definecolor{LinkColor}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks=true,%        Aktivieren von farbigen Links im Dokument (keine Rahmen)
    linkcolor=LinkColor,%    Farbe festlegen.
    citecolor=LinkColor,%    Farbe festlegen.
    filecolor=LinkColor,%    Farbe festlegen.
    menucolor=LinkColor,%    Farbe festlegen.
    urlcolor=LinkColor,%     Farbe von URL's im Dokument.
    bookmarksnumbered=true%  Überschriftsnummerierung im PDF Inhalt anzeigen.
}
%Zeilenabstand 1.2
\linespread{1.2}
%Kopf- und Fusszeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%Kopfzeile links bzw. innen
\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{someone}}
%Kopfzeile rechts bzw. aussen
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
%Linie oben
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
%Fusszeile links bzw. innen
\fancyfoot[L]{\textsf{Something}}
%Fusszeile rechts bzw. aussen
\fancyfoot[R]{{\textsf{\pagemark}}}
%Linie unten
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Setup for listings.
\lstset{basicstyle=\small}
\lstset{language=C}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\newpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\section*{Affirmation}
\newpage
\section*{Abstract}

\newpage

\section*{Acknowledgements}

\newpage



\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents


\newpage




\end{document}
```

As it can be seen affirmation, abstract come before the table of content.

And I would want my table of content to look something like this:

[image: Table of content]
Edit: My document class is  `scrartcl` and I don't use frontmatter.

Comment: Are you using `book` class? Are you trying to put the section in `frontmatter`? Please give a MWE so that those who try to answer will be spared of guess work and your chances of getting a specific answer improve.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks for reminding, I have edited the question.

Comment: @HarishKumar My MWE is more than 180 lines, I  think if I add it, the description would look elongated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to write a report/book. In that case you should better consider using `book` or `scrreprt` or `scrbook`. Hence you can put `frontmatter` `mainmatter` and `backmatter` easily. However, the following works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside, paper=a4,pagesize=pdftex, liststotoc, bibtotoc]{scrartcl}
%Einstellungen der Seitenrnder
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Umlaute ermglichen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[tight,TABTOPCAP]{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% macros - newly defined by htrsek
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{TODO: #1}}}
\newcommand{\comment}[2]{\textcolor{orange}{\textbf{\textit{\textless Comment (#1): #2\textgreater}}}}
\newcommand{\inprogress}[3]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{InProgress: #1}}}
\newcommand{\translate}[4]{\textcolor{green}{\textbf{(#1)}}}
\newcommand{\flexWARE}{\textsuperscript{flex}WARE }
\newcommand{\thedate}{\today}
%[BC] Using the listing package for source code embedding.
\usepackage{listings} \lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt} \lstset{language=Perl} 

 %PDF Kram
\usepackage[%
    pdftitle={something},% Titel des PDF Dokuments.
    pdfauthor={someone},%Autor des PDF Dokuments.
    pdfsubject={something},%Thema des PDF Dokuments.
    pdfcreator={MiKTeX, LaTeX, hyperref, KOMA-Script},%Erzeuger des PDF Dokuments.
    pdfkeywords={project title},% auch fr PDF 
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,% Inhaltsverzeichnis anzeigen beim 
    %pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,%Dokumenttitel statt Dateiname 
    pdflang=en%Sprache des Dokuments.
]{hyperref}

\definecolor{LinkColor}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks=true,%        Aktivieren von farbigen Links im Dokument (keine Rahmen)
    linkcolor=LinkColor,%    Farbe festlegen.
    citecolor=LinkColor,%    Farbe festlegen.
    filecolor=LinkColor,%    Farbe festlegen.
    menucolor=LinkColor,%    Farbe festlegen.
    urlcolor=LinkColor,%     Farbe von URL's im Dokument.
    bookmarksnumbered=true%  Überschriftsnummerierung im PDF Inhalt anzeigen.
}
%Zeilenabstand 1.2
\linespread{1.2}
%Kopf- und Fusszeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%Kopfzeile links bzw. innen
\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{someone}}
%Kopfzeile rechts bzw. aussen
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
%Linie oben
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
%Fusszeile links bzw. innen
\fancyfoot[L]{\textsf{Something}}
%Fusszeile rechts bzw. aussen
\fancyfoot[R]{{\textsf{\pagemark}}}
%Linie unten
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Setup for listings.
\lstset{basicstyle=\small}
\lstset{language=C}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\clearpage
%\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section*{Affirmation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Affirmation}
\clearpage
\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\clearpage

\section*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{some section}
\subsection{some sub section}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude the numbering of sections by using `\section*{something}`.